# windows authentication in web api 2

Tags: c#, angularjs, authentication, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2

I create angular js application for client side and for server side I use asp.net web api2.
Now I want to integrate **windows authentication** for this application.
How to integrate Windows authentication for this scenario.
I not want simple iis based windows authentication in web api 2.

Comment: This question seems to me to be way to broad of a subject.  Google is your friend in this case and will show you numerous examples of how to set up the authentication you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

If you are opting for OWIN hosted Web API,

```
using (WebApp.Start(url, (app) =>
{
    HttpListener listener = (HttpListener)appBuilder.Properties["System.Net.HttpListener"];
    listener.AuthenticationSchemes = AuthenticationSchemes.IntegratedWindowsAuthentication;
    ...
}
```